# How to avoid having to place <%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.Helpers" %> on top of every view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on my first asp.net mvc application and I'm using custom helpers like the Html.Label() from the example on the official site.

For having access to Html.Label, I have to place

```
<%@ Import Namespace="BRG.Helpers" %>
```

at the top of every view.

Is there a way to avoid having to do that? I've read somewhere someone mentioning something about the web.config, but I can't find it anywhere..

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649593/using-default-namespaces-in-net-mvc-for-views-without-using-import

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the namespace to your `web.config` in `configuration\system.web\pages\namespaces` like:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages ...>
            <controls ... />
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="BRG.Helpers" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can do this in either the root `web.config` or the one in the `Views` directory.

Comment: Probably it works, but I was using portable areas from MvcContrib and it didn't work.