# How to inherit from a library in a MVC.NET view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckfinder

I am trying to implement CKFinder in my MVC.Net website, but the default setup only works for regular asp.net websites, so I am trying to alter it to work.

One page inherits from a library CKFinder.Connector.Connector. In the old days my aspx would just `inherit="CKFinder.Connector.Connector"`, but how is this done in MVC.NET?

Is `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CKFinder.Connector.Connector>"` the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this namespace is used frequently, you should probably consider adding it to the namespaces node in your `Views/Web.config` file.

This ensures that all pages will have access to this namespace, and intellisense will be available also. This has also been discussed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649593/using-default-namespaces-in-net-mvc-for-views-without-using-import).

The XML structure would be as follows.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="CKFinder.Connector.Connector" /> <!-- <<< Your entry here  -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>  
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The `namespaces` node may not exist, so you should add it inside the `pages` node (which should exist).

Answer (score 0):

`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CKFinder.Connector.Connector>"` would set up CKFinder.Connector.Connector as the strongly-typed Model object for your View page. This would work for you if you're trying to access properties on a Connector instance in your markup using the `<%= Model.SomePropertyOnConnectorObject %>` syntax.

If instead you need to reference CKFinder.Connector.Connector as a namespace, you would need to add the following line below the page directives and before any markup:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="CKFinder.Connector.Connector" %>
```